# Prolog Family Tree Compile Errors

Tags: prolog

I've been getting two error messages when compiling this:

```
"Clauses of (-)/1 are not together in source-file" and
"Singleton variables: [X]"
```

...those two being examples of the errors I've been getting...

I've tried removing a few of the facts in my source code so that none of the facts would clash, and I've tried just defining the people as atoms rather than clauses...neither of them worked as I'd hoped, any ideas?

```
male(X).
female(X).
parent(X,Y).
father(X,Y):- male(X), parent(X,Y).
mother(X,Y):- female(X), parent(X,Y).
descendant(X,Y):- parent(Y,X).
sibling(X,Y):- descendant(X,Z), descendant(Y,Z).
brother(X,Y):- male(X), sibling(X,Y).
sister(X,Y):- female(X), sibling(X,Y).
grandparent(X,Y):- parent(X,Z), parent(Z,Y).
paternalgrandparent(X,Y):- father(X,Z), father(Z,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):- ancestor(X,Z), parent(Z,Y).
male(edward).
male(sean).
male(kevin).
female(vicky).
male(malcolm).
male(claude).
male(matthew).
female(stephania).
male(kurt).
male(david).
male(mark).
male(raymond).
female(therese).
female(nadine).
female(nathalie).
male(richard).
female(mary).
male(john).
female(lilian).
female(inez).
male(william).
female(rose).
male(richie).
female(alice).
brother(edward,vicky).
brother(kevin,sean).
brother(sean,vicky).
sister(vicky,edward).
brother(malcolm,claude).
brother(claude,malcolm).
brother(matthew,stephania).
brother(kurt,matthew).
sister(stephania,kurt).
brother(david,mark).
brother(mark,david).
sister(therese,nadine).
sister(nadine,therese).
sister(lilian,inez).
sister(inez,lilian).
father(david,edward).
mother(therese,edward).
father(mark,malcolm).
mother(nathalie,malcolm).
father(raymond,matthew).
mother(nadine,matthew).
father(richard,david).
mother(mary,david).
father(john,therese).
mother(lilian,therese).
paternalgrandparent(richard,edward).
grandparent(mary,edward).
grandparent(lilian,edward).
grandparent(john,edward).
paternalgrandparent(richard,malcolm).
grandparent(mary,malcolm).
grandparent(lilian,matthew).
grandparent(john,matthew).
father(william,richard).
mother(rose,richard).
paternalgrandparent(william,david).
grandparent(rose,david).
father(richie,william).
mother(alice,william).
paternalgrandparent(richie,richard).
grandparent(alice,richard).
ancestor(richie,william).
ancestor(alice,william).
ancestor(william,richard).
ancestor(rose,richard).
ancestor(richard,david).
ancestor(mary,david).
ancestor(david,edward).
ancestor(therese,edward).
ancestor(lilian,therese).
ancestor(john,therese).
ancestor(lilian,nadine).
ancestor(john,nadine).
ancestor(richard,mark).
ancestor(mary,mark).
```

Comment: The simplest way of formatting your program on Stack Overflow is to select the parts that you want to format, and click the curly braces button `{}` on the editor's toolbar at the top.

Comment: thanks guys your answers really helped me out but I've got another problem apparently...
I keep posing queries, but even for the false statements I'm getting a "true" return...even with atoms that don't exist (posed the query "ancestor(leo,edward). and got true"...any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If this is anything like yahoo answers, I'd rather wait until it goes to voting since both answers helped me out..
Also the follow-up question was regarding this program, not another so I thought it would be a good idea to get questions relevant to this program dealt with on the same page...

Comment: Questions and answers go to voting at the time they get posted. Although a follow-up question has to do with the same program, I imagine the program is quite a bit different, and you are asking about logical errors, not compile errors. On SO newer questions tend to have more attention (although in less traveled tags such as `[Prolog]` questions tend to stay new for longer periods of time). You can post a link to this question from a new question, but the info from the answers below would not be of much help, because both answers concentrate on fixing syntactic, not logical, issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "clauses are not together" is the simplest error to fix: simply re-arrange the facts of your program in such a way that all facts with the same name (e.g. `male/1`, `female/1`, etc.) appear together in the source of your program.

The "singleton variables" errors are coming from these lines:

```
male(X).
female(X).
parent(X,Y).
```

A variable is singleton when it is mentioned only once in the enture rule or a fact. In case when you do want these variables, they should be replaced with underscores. However, in your case you do not want these variables: otherwise, a rule like this

```
male(_).
```

would assert that anybody is a male, and you do not want that to happen. You should simply remove these rules to make the singleton errors go away.

However, the biggest problem with your program appears that you are trying to define facts for things that you have already defined through rules. The facts that you need are `male/1`, `female/1`, and `parent/2`. Everything else can be correctly derived through rules.

Answer (score 0):

They should be only warnings not errors.
The first message is telling you to define predicates all together.

So for example

```
male(edward).
male(sean).
male(kevin).
female(vicky).
male(malcolm).
```

is not good.
The reason for this is that you you spread the definition of male around, the code becomes totally unreadable.

The second is telling you that if you use a variable in the head, you should use it in the body.

So for example

```
male(X).
```

Is not good. You can write

```
male(_).
```

Again, very often singleton variables cause errors in what you are trying to write, so it's better to use _ to make their use explicit.